# zksync-web3 not imported properly

Tags: javascript, html, web3js

I would like to use zksync-web3 in my dApp but I usually build frontends in pure HTML/CSS/JS. I cannot seems to get zksync-web3 to work like Web3js. Some minimal code:

index.html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.0.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/browse/zksync-web3@0.14.3/build/src/index.js"></script>
```

index.js file

```
const GAME_CONTRACT_ABI = await fetch("./game_abi.json");

const zkSyncProvider = new zkSync.Provider("https://zksync2-testnet.zksync.dev");
const signer = new zkSync.Web3Provider(window.ethereum).getSigner();
    return contract = new zkSync.Contract(
        GAME_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        GAME_CONTRACT_ABI,
        signer
);
```

What'sthe right way to call the ABI and zksync-web3 package?

Tried to dpeloy site and gets promise rejected due to inability to read "zksync"

Answer (score 0):

I think your CDN for zksync-web3 address is wrong. 
try : "https://unpkg.com/zksync-web3@0.14.3/build/src/index.js"
instead of "https://unpkg.com/browse/zksync-web3@0.14.3/build/src/index.js"